# A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm trying to download a collection of documents from mongodb, using nodejs, to the browser, using backbone. I can use a simple ajax request but I would like to take advantage of Backbone, so Backbone should do the GET request.

There is an empty collection:

```
//create a model and collection for task_lists
var MTaskList = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: 'Untitled Task List'
    },
    urlRoot: '/task_list'
});
var cTaskLists = new Backbone.Collection({
    model: MTaskList,
    url: '/task_list'
});
```

When I try to fetch the data from server:

```
cTaskLists.fetch({reset: true, data: {workspace: sWsUrl}}); //ask for the data to server
```

It throws the error:
    Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

I tried with different combinations of url but same error is always thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter expected in a [collection constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor) is a list of models, the options hash comes second:

> **constructor / initialize**  new Collection([models], [options])
>   When creating a Collection, you may choose to pass in the initial array of
>   models.

Try

```
var cTaskLists = new Backbone.Collection([], {
    model: MTaskList,
    url: '/task_list'
});
```

And a Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/L4xsJ/